# Как изменить формат Url для пагинации с помощью .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, apache, joomla, pagination

Задача в том чтобы изменить формат url c /vse?start=24 на vse/page/2 система Joomla 3 долго ковырялся в файлах /libraries/joomla/html/pagination.php и /includes/router.php нашел что откуда берется, и что куда передается, но сменить принцип отображения так и не смог. Может как то можно это сделать через .htaccess?

Comment: `/vse?start=24` на `vse/page/2` ? описка? Может быть так: `vse/page/24` ?

Comment: Не , все верно с /vse?start=24 на vse/page/2. А если /vse?start=24 на vse/page/24. то какой есть вариант?

Answer (score 2):

Пробуйте.

```
RewriteRule ^vse/page/(\d) /vse?start=$14 [L]
```

Comment: Почти, выдает 404. Суть в том что есть категории с разными названиями. например
krovati?start=24 должна быть krovati/page/2.

Comment: @Merouzy мой пример - это "решение в вакууме". Оно работает, если нет больше никаких других правил и просто существует каталог `/vse/page/2` в котором, например, лежит файл `index.html`. В вашем случае явно все отправляется еще в какой-нибудь `router.php`. Если вы сейчас у себя обратитесь по ссылке `http://site.com/krovati/page/2` будет 404 или страница откроется без всяких редиректов и прочего?

Comment: @Merouzy либо я не правильно понял изначально. Вы хотите чтобы вводя ссылки /vse/page/2 в бэкграунде это работало как /vse?start=24

Comment: Именно вот так.  "Вы хотите чтобы вводя ссылки /vse/page/2 в бэкграунде это работало как /vse?start=24"

Comment: @Merouzy совсем простой вариант добавил в ответе. Но остается вопрос, как связаны числа "2" и "24". Плюс - после редиректа изменится адресная строка, а я так полагаю, это не желательно.

Comment: на уровне php  могу с условно krovati?start=24 . сделать krovati?start=2

Comment: @Merouzy если так сделаете, то и в правиле последнюю 4-ку надо убрать: `RewriteRule ^vse/page/(\d)/vse?start=$1 [L]`

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Буду пробовать

Comment: Связь между 2 и 24 следующая. На странице отображается 24 товара. Следовательно первая страничка будет иметь адрес /vse?start=$0, вторая /vse?start=$24, третья /vse?start=$48. А хотелось бы что бы пользователь видел на первой страничке vse, на второй vse/page/2, на третьей vse/page/3 и т.д.